# Kind of a silly question regarding compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis

If $T \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ is a compact operator, how about $-T$, i.e. it's additive inverse? Does this notation even make any sense with regard to the minus sign? Is it trivial?

Further, suppose we have another compact operator $S \in \mathcal{B}(X)$. I know that $S+T$ is compact, but how about $S-T$ or $T-S$?

Comment: Yes, Banach spaces are real-vector-spaces (at the least), so $-T=(-1)T$ is also an operator. As the images of the unit ball under both operators agree, each is compact iff the other is.

Comment: I guess my second question also gets answered once it is confirmed that $-T$ is also compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of compact operators on a Banach space is itself a Banach space, with the supremum norm. So linear combinations and limits of compact operators are again compact.